# Probability of the lim sup under certain conditions of the events

Tags: probability-theory

Exam review question:

> Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of events on a probability space $(\Omega,B,P).$  Assume that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) = \infty$$ and  $$\lim \inf \frac{\sum_{j,k \le n}P(A_j \cup A_k)}{\left(\sum_{k \le n} P(A_k)\right)^2} \le 1.$$
>
> Show that $P[A_n i.o.] = 1$.

I first thought that somehow I might be able to show that the inequality is a sufficient condition for independence of the $A_n$'s, which would allow me to use the Borel Zero-One Law.

I also thought it might work to use Fatou's lemma and somehow use the inequality to show $\lim \sup P(A_n) \ge 1$.

Currently the implementation of either strategy is eluding me.  Any thoughts?